# Can't Get a 3rd Party Symfony Bundle to Install

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php

I'm trying to install a 3rd party bundle into my Smfony2 website. The web page for it is [here](http://knpbundles.com/ideatosrl/FlickrApiBundle). The documentation looked straight forward until I tried it. I found I needed to run composer.phar. When I ran "php composer.phar update", it updated a bunch of my bundles and completed without error, but didn't appear to install flickrapibundle. As instructed I add the line "ideato/flickr-api-bundle": "dev-master", to my composer.json file prior to running the command. Do I have to download the bundle and put it somewhere for composer to find it? I would think so, but the documentation makes no mention of it. When I tried to reload one my pages, I get the white screen of death. It's caused by an attempt to instantiate on object of the class.

Comment: Did you verify that your bundle was downloaded by looking in the `vendor` folder?

Comment: With files being two years old, and still no tagged release, and looking at the `composer.json` file, I think there is some dependency on symfony components missing. And I probably wouldn't want to use software that stays in "development" forever. You have to find out which class is missing.

Comment: @Sven, there was nothing in the vendor directory for it after running composer.phar. I did see some newer dates in github for the project, but I am suspicious of its viability.

Comment: I installed this successfully yesterday, it created the directory `vendor/ideato/flickr-api-bundle` as expected and I was able to add the line `new Ideato\FlickrApiBundle\FlickrApiBundle(),` to my **AppKernel.php**. If you're still having the problem, can you post your entire **composer.json** file here or on Pastebin?

Comment: Thanks @fazy. I ended up writing my own classes to encapsulate the flickr API. It was more fun.